# jquery accordion menu default closed on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to save up some space on my vertical accordion menu by making it more interactive.

i managed to get the menu to physically work and css styled as i need it.

problem is upon page load 1x category is "open" if i remove the class="open" style it doesn't hide the category.

this can be shown: [jsfiddle (category 2 is my problem!)](http://jsfiddle.net/836rM/10/)

i'm not at all comfortable with jquery so i'm not sure if this can be changed to default all categories "closed" until its clicked.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("ul.accordion span.name").click(function()
            {
                var $li = $( this ).parent("li").has("ul");

                if( $li.hasClass("open") )
                {
                    $li.find("ul").slideUp('slow', function( ){
                        $li.removeClass("open");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $li.addClass("open");
                    $li.find("ul").slideDown('slow');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

can this be edited in the jquery script i would ultimetly like multiple drop down category but this will actually take more space up that the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inserted at the top this line in document ready function :

```
 $('li.open').removeClass('open').find('ul').hide();
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/9kjpn4j7/][1]

**DEMO:** [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/9kjpn4j7/